# Checking every row in a Python matrix and change each third index

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, indexing, slice

im having difficulties in a exercice using matrix:
I need to make the 4th number in each row a sum of the others 3; Basically i just need to change the second and fourth row but i cant change then directly.

I need to use a "for" loop to check every row and change the index[3] to a sum of the index 0-2.

```
matrix = [ 
    [1, 1, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 2, 7],
    [3, 3, 3, 9],
    [4, 4, 4, 13]
]
```

I know that there is numpy and things like that but i dont think im allowed to use it for this exercise. If you have anyway to help i would be very grateful!

Thanks!! ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ

I think i need to slice the matrix and use the for loop to check every row and change the last number of every row to a sum of the others three. I dont know if this is possible as i cant quite do it :(!

Comment: What's your best attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use the for loop to check every row and change the last number of every row to a sum of the others three

```py
matrix = [ 
    [1, 1, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 2, 7],
    [3, 3, 3, 9],
    [4, 4, 4, 13]
]

for row in matrix:
    row[-1] = sum(row[:-1])
for row in matrix:
    print(row)

#[1, 1, 1, 3]
#[2, 2, 2, 6]
#[3, 3, 3, 9]
#[4, 4, 4, 12]
```